# Reuse ActiveX control sub

Tags: excel, vba

VBA Beginner here. How can I reuse `ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()` with `ComboBox2_DropButtonClick()`?

Comment: Create another subroutine and place its name inside both `ComboBox_DropButtonClick` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can simple call the event code like doing for a simple Sub:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
   Debug.Print "Combo 1 clicked..."
   ComboBox2_DropButtonClick
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_DropButtonClick()
   Debug.Print "Combo 2 clicked..."
End Sub
```

But I avoid using this event. Usually, it is triggered twice...

Comment: Somebody answered this already and it worked. thx for ur suggestions  :)

Comment: @Dunno dotcom I am afraid nobody suggests that. They suggested to use a common `Sub` to be called by both events. I'm just showing how to call the event directly...

Comment: Oh, is that so? but sub routine is what I exactly needed because I'll be adding `byval`  in arguments :)

Answer (score 1):

I just create a module, `Module1`, containing the subroutine `test`:

```
Sub test()
MsgBox ("Hello")
End Sub
```

Then, I put a button on my Excel sheet, and when clicked, the subroutine `test` got launched:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Module1.test
End Sub
```

You can do something similar.

Comment: Somebody answered this already and it worked :)